# Online Shops - Performance Measuring

Tags: customer, performance

I would like to know if it is possible to have access to information regarding the performance that a shop is having in a specific country, such as what are their overall ratings and their overall sales.

I am going to start my online shop and I would like to gather some insights from the best shops that there is out there, but I did not find this functionality anywhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for this kind of data on other shops - you are not going to find it easily (or at all).  Would you want to give another store owner a detailed breakdown of your sales figures?  If you want this data for your own shop then Analytics combined with standard Magento data is likely to do all you need.